# Should you always initialise C++ std::vectors?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector

I am coming from a C background where, as common practice, variables are always initialized to prevent undefined behavior. You normally, don't have any meaningful value when declaring the variables, you set the variables to 0 or {}.

I am new to C++ and I am about to code an app, which C++ classes will contain std::vectors with very long sizes... so I am just wondering if the same principles apply to std::vectors or not... and save a few loops of computational requirements

Thanks!

Comment: vector constructors initialize its contents, no extra loops needed.

Comment: u can't have an uninitialized `std::vector`

Comment: You may want a good C++ textbook. `std::vector` is not that special - like most C++ classes, it has constructors. This is a big difference with C. Constructors initialize variables and other objects.

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to create a Vector, which is not initialized. The default constructor constructs an empty container with a default-constructed allocator.

Here are some examples on how to initialise a Vector if you already know its content or size.

```cpp
// Will be an initialised empty Vector
std::vector<std::string> words;

// c++11 initializer list syntax:
std::vector<std::string> words1 {"the", "frogurt", "is", "also", "cursed"};
std::cout << "words1: " << words1 << '\n';
 
// words2 == words1
std::vector<std::string> words2(words1.begin(), words1.end());
std::cout << "words2: " << words2 << '\n';
 
// words3 == words1
std::vector<std::string> words3(words1);
std::cout << "words3: " << words3 << '\n';
 
// words4 is {"Mo", "Mo", "Mo", "Mo", "Mo"}
std::vector<std::string> words4(5, "Mo");
std::cout << "words4: " << words4 << '\n';
```

Comment: I think I have just found what my issue was... I was incorrectly using the `std::vector::reserve` method to allocate memory for the vector, but I have just understood that that does not modify the size of the vector at all... so it does not intialise anything at...

Comment: @WewillSee, You should be careful with default initialized empty vector. Try access elements of such vector using subscript operator `[]` may cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a vector it gets default initialized,  so it's up to you if you want to initialize it with user default values or not.
You will always get an empty vector container if you don't initialize it.

You have different ways to initialize vector to defaults like [provided by @nils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926309/should-you-always-initialise-c-stdvectors)

but the important thing to note is std::vector encapsulates dynamic size arrays so the memory allocated to them is generally more than a static array as memory is allocated for the future growth of vector also.

Refer [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more details .
and the [capacity()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) function to understand the memory allocation to vectors .

Comment: Do you mean "value initialized" instead of "default initialized"?

Answer (score -2):

```
std::vector<int> vc1(5); // number of elements
// 0 0 0 0 0

std::vector<int> vc2(5, 0); // number of elements, value of each element
// 0 0 0 0 0
```

That two vectors, vc1 and vc2, are same way to create new vector.